# Need to "balance" a cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have a test cluster I built, and upon looking at it when running a nodetool status I have the data distributed amongst the four nodes as such:

--  Address      Load       Tokens  Owns

UN  NODE3        1.61 GB    1       14.6%
UN  NODE2        3.14 GB    1       19.4%
UN  NODE1        7.68 GB    1       63.9%
UN  NODE4        5.85 GB    1       2.0%

Now all nodes were added before I ingested data into the database, but I think I probably screwed up by not manually setting the token info prior to bringing data into the cluster.

My question is how best to readjust this to more evenly distribute the data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are not using Vnodes (which you are not since you have 1 token per node), you can move tokens on each node to evenly distribute your ring.   To do this, do the following:

1. Calculate the tokens to assign your nodes based on number of nodes in your cluster.  You can use a tool like [cassandra token calculator](http://www.geroba.com/cassandra/cassandra-token-calculator/).  With Murmur3Partitioner and 4 nodes you could use: (`-9223372036854775808`
   `-4611686018427387904` `0` `4611686018427387904`)
2. One node at a time use [nodetool move](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/tools/toolsMove.html) to move the node to the new token (i.e. `nodetool move -- 0`) and wait for it to complete.  This may take a while.  It may also be wise to choose which nodes to move to which token based on their current proximity to the token they are moving to.
3. Usually its a good idea to do a `nodetool cleanup` on that node afterwords to cleanup data no longer belonging to that node.

Answer (score 1):

+1 on Andy's points. I'd like to add one more thing.

To ensure you get an accurate Owns %, you must specify a Cassandra Keyspace for `nodetool status <ks>`